# extracting a dataframe from a list over many objects

Tags: r, lapply

I have over a 1000 objects (`z`) in R, each containing three dataframes (`df1`, `df2`, `df3`) with different structures.

> `z1$df1` … `z1000$df1`
>
> `z1$df2` … `z1000$df2`
>
> `z1$df3` … `z1000$df3`

I created a list of these objects (list1 thus contains z1 thru z1000) and tried to use `lapply` to extract one type of dataframe (`df2`) for all objects, and then merge them to one single dataframe.

#### Extraction:

For a single object it would look like this:

```
df15<- z15$df2 # I transferred the index of z to the extracted df
```

I tried some code with `lapply`, ignoring the transfer of the index (I can create another list for that). However I don’t know what function I should use.

```
List2 <- lapply(list1, function(x))
```

I try to avoid using a loop because there's so many and vectorization is so much quicker. I have the idea I'm looking at it from the wrong angle.

Subsequent merging can be done as follows:

```
merged <- do.call(rbind, list2)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Clarification: `df1`, `df2`, `df3` have different structures but structures (number, name of columns)  of all `df1`s in the 1000 `z_n` lists are identical?

Comment: `df15<- z15$df2 ` line is confusing. Why do you want to assign `df2` type over `df15`? Don't you want to merge all `df2` types together in one dataframe?

Comment: df15 should read newdf15. The reason of transferring the id of the original file is because it allows me to trace back the origin of the data. Using pattern I can still merge with similar but not identical names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be using `lapply` to extract `data.frame` and then use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`.

```
## The data
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), name = c(LETTERS[1:10]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 11:20, name = LETTERS[11:20], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3 <- data.frame(id = 21:30, name = LETTERS[15:24], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df4 <- data.frame(id = 121:130, name = LETTERS[15:24], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

z1 <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
z2 <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
z3 <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
z4 <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df4) #DFs can contain different data

# z <- list(z1, z2, z3, z4)
# Dynamically populate list z with many list object
z <- as.list(mget(paste("z",1:4,sep="")))


df1_all <- bind_rows(lapply(z, function(x) x$df1))
df2_all <- bind_rows(lapply(z, function(x) x$df2))
df3_all <- bind_rows(lapply(z, function(x) x$df3))


## Result for df3_all
> tail(df3_all)
##    id name
## 35 125    S
## 36 126    T
## 37 127    U
## 38 128    V
## 39 129    W
## 40 130    X
```

Comment: Thnaks for your code. I get an error "Error in x$df1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @mauricevergeer You can get that error if you don't pass `list` to `lapply` function. Are you using code posted in this answer?

Comment: yes, I used the above suggested code. To make sure I used "as.list" to create the list.

Comment: @mauricevergeer please share `str(z)` from your code.

Comment: OK, my list was incorrect, made up of character: $ : chr "df84". I tried your way to create the list and that works. :-) SO I was able to create the merged dataframes for a limited number of objects. My final question is how I can create such a list not for four objects but for +1000 objects? Thanks for your input

Comment: @mauricevergeer one option is use `names` to set name of dataframes. something like `z1 <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4);
names(z1) <- paste("df",1:4, sep="")` will set names dynamically.

Comment: @mauricevergeer I have modified my answer to dynamically create list for many list object. `z <- as.list(mget(paste("z",1:4,sep="")))` has been added now.

Comment: Thanks, it's similar to my code: `z <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "list"), mget(ls(pattern= "df")))` I like the pattern element to be sure I exclude other data objects not fitting the pattern

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to pull out all the `df1`s and `rbind` them together then do the same for the other dataframes. You can use `purrr::map_dfr` to extract a column from each element of the list and rowbind them together.

```
library('tidyverse')

dummy_df <- list(
  df1 = iris,
  df2 = cars,
  df3 = CO2)

list1 <- list(
  z1 = dummy_df,
  z2 = dummy_df,
  z3 = dummy_df)

df1 <- map_dfr(list1, 'df1')
df2 <- map_dfr(list1, 'df2')
df3 <- map_dfr(list1, 'df3')
```

If you wanted to do it in base R, you can use `lapply`.

```
df1 <- lapply(list1, function(x) x$df1)
df1_merged <- do.call(rbind, df1)
```

Comment: Good solution. I would have preferred `bind_rows` from `dplyr` to better speed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lapply(list1, "[[", "df2")
```

or if you want to `rbind` them together:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(list1, "[[", "df2"))
```

The row names in the resulting data frame will identify the origin of each row.

No packages are used.

### Note

We can use this input to test the code above. `BOD` is a built-in data frame:

```
z <- list(df1 = BOD, df2 = BOD, df3 = BOD)
list1 <- list(z1 = z, z2 = z)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I get the error message: "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: The code shown does not produce such error message with the input shown reproducibly in the Note but without a reproducible example one can't know what you have done.

Comment: Thanks, my original list was faulty. My mistake. That's why it did produced the error. Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

THere's also `data.table::rbindlist`, which is likely faster than `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))` or `dplyr::bind_rows`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(list1, "[[", "df2"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Not yet tried data.table in general, but read some very positive reviews about it.